# Are GUIDs generated on Windows CE devices using the .NET Compact Framework 3.5 still statistically unique?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, guid

I know that you can bang away at GUID generation on single and multiple machines and it's statistically unlikely to ever generate the same GUID twice.

There is lots of information on the internet proving this.

Can the same be said of 100s of Windows CE 4, 5 & 6 devices running applications based on the .NET Compact Framework 3.5 generating GUIDs?

I'm assuming yes but can't find any information proving that the WinCE OS uses random numbers and that they are suitably random.

Can anybody provide such information and references?

Thanks,

J.

Comment: Stackoverflow's perpetuum mobile question.

Comment: On a side node: there is no such thing as a random number :-)

Comment: Ah yes, but this time it's on Windows CE!! So it's a completely different question... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an [early article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446557.aspx) on Guid for the .NET Compact Framework

> The .NET Compact Framework team constantly made tradeoffs between the
>   framework footprint size, performance, and implementation time. The
>   full .NET Framework Guid.NewGuid method calls the Windows API function
>   CoCreateGuid that calls UuidCreate to generate globally unique 128-bit
>   numbers. Unfortunately, these functions are not supported on the
>   Pocket PC, so the Guid.NewGuid method was not implemented for the .NET
>   Compact Framework.

This article proposes an algorithm which equals the windows version

> It turns out that it's easy to write a custom implementation of the
>   Guid.NewGuid method. The following shows a test application that
>   generates GUIDs on the Pocket PC. It uses a custom class called
>   PocketGuid, that uses the same algorithm as desktop GUIDs and is
>   discussed in more detail later in this paper.

Since 2.0 the actual compact framework contains the `Guid.NewGuid` method, I would think they included the mentioned code which results in the same strongness / uniqueness of Guids on WinCE.

Comment: I think my best solution is to just say that the .NET 2.0 CF method for creating a GUID uses the same method in the PocketGuid example.

Comment: Although I've already had to argue that the method for getting a random method in the PocketGuid is _random enough_ ("But what if the two handhelds are booted at the same time? It _could_ create the same numer!")

Comment: As stated in the article the function not only uses the timestamp but some more hardware related information. So it should not produce colliding guids when two devices are booted at the same time, hopefully :)